# Access generated UUID's in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker container that runs fine and has a UUID to reference the sandbox. I'm trying to add more functionality to the app, and want to be able to access the UUID generated and reference it in a python file. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this:

1. If you want the full UUID, you can achieve it looking inside the file */proc/self/cgroup*, then doing a simple `cut` on it should be enough.

   So from the container:

   ```
   head -1 /proc/self/cgroup | cut -d/ -f3
   ```

   Full working example:

   ```
   ~ % docker exec -ti e5867f7e3597861284644d15b33f94a800542e1b2e36a375a4be7d1f26a4fd56 ash
   ~ # head -1 /proc/self/cgroup | cut -d/ -f3
   e5867f7e3597861284644d15b33f94a800542e1b2e36a375a4be7d1f26a4fd56
   ```
2. The file */proc/1/cpuset* will also give the full UUID, so you could go by

   ```
   basename $(cat /proc/1/cpuset)
   ```

   Full working example:

   ```
   ~ % docker exec -ti e5867f7e3597861284644d15b33f94a800542e1b2e36a375a4be7d1f26a4fd56 ash
   ~ # basename $(cat /proc/1/cpuset)
   e5867f7e3597861284644d15b33f94a800542e1b2e36a375a4be7d1f26a4fd56
   ```
3. To get the short form of the UUID, there is even a simpler approach, via the hostname:

   ```
   cat /etc/hostname
   ```

   And all its equivalent:

   - ```
     uname -n
     ```
   - ```
     hostname
     ```
   - ```
     echo $HOSTNAME
     ```

   Full working example:

   ```
   ~ % docker exec -ti e5867f7e3597861284644d15b33f94a800542e1b2e36a375a4be7d1f26a4fd56 ash
   ~ # cat /etc/hostname
   e5867f7e3597
   ```